# Imprimir el número menor de cada fila de una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al imprimir los menores de cada fila de la matriz casi siempre me imprime los números que no son los menores. ¿En que estoy fallando?

> 31. Leer una matriz 4x6 entera y mostrar en pantalla los menores por fila

Este es mi código:

```
try:
    matriz=[]

    for a in range(0,3):
        filas=[]
        for b in range(0,2):
            llenar_matriz=int(input("Digite un numero para llenar la matriz: "))
            filas.append(llenar_matriz)
        matriz.append(filas)


    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        for d in range(len(matriz[c])):
            menor=matriz[0][0]
            numero=matriz[c][d]

            if numero<menor:
                menor=numero
        print(menor)

    print(matriz)


except ValueError:
    print("El valor es incorrecto")
```

Comment: Por si te interesa, puedes usar la función `min()` para obtener el número más pequeño de una lista. Sería algo así como `menor = min(matriz[c])`

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que para cada elemento redefines `menor`:

```
for c in range(len(matriz)):
    for d in range(len(matriz[c])):
        menor=matriz[c][d]            <<<<<<<<<< 
        numero=matriz[c][d]
```

de hecho, en todas las iteraciones `menor` y `numero` tiene el mismo valor, por lo que `if numero<menor: siempre` es falso. Al final te imprimirá el último elemento de la fila siempre.

Sin tocar mucho tu código, dado que necesitas el menor de cada fila, puedes hacer los siguiente:

```
for c in range(len(matriz)):
    menor = matriz[c][0]                # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    for d in range(1, len(matriz[c])):
        numero = matriz[c][d]
        if numero < menor:
            menor = numero
    print(menor)
```

Cuando comenzamos a recorrer una fila igualamos `menor` al primer elemento de la fila. Después solo lo modificamos cuando encontramos un `item` que sea menor a éste.

Supongo que se trata de una tarea, por lo que no podrás explotar todo lo que ofrece el lenguaje. Esto se puede hacer más simple y eficiente con la ayuda del built-in `min`, por ejemplo:

```
for i, fila in enumerate(matriz):
    print(f"El menor de la fila {i + 1} es {min(fila)}."
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ya hice la corrección que me dijiste y ya me dio gracias